# Macro to select text block with the same style

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

In Word 2016, there is already build-in option "Select all instances of style". Here is how it works:

[image]

I want to implement something similar with VBA. It should select only one text block. The only one, in which the user's caret is currently located. For example, if caret located somewhere near `Bar()`, the result should be:

[image]

It will be very useful for selecting (and copy/cut) **large** code blocks in documents.

Any ideas how it could be done?

(I know, Stack Overflow isn't "free coding service", and it's a good practice to show some partly-working code, as evidence of your own efforts. However, it's also a bit hard to get into VBA "from the scratch", because I never have worked with it. Only JavaScript in my previous practice).

Answer (score 2):

Press Alt+F11 to open Visual Basic Editor

then choose Insert > New Module

paste the following code:

```
Sub myMacro1()
    WordBasic.SelectSimilarFormatting
End Sub
```

Note: This is for office 2007, not sure if its the same in Word 2016. if you can do something from menus.. you can try to Record Macro (from Developer tab) and see the codes generated automatically by word to customize them.

Comment: Hi. It works in Word 2016, but it selects all instances of style, like shown in my 1st image. That's not what I want. The desired result is shown in my 2nd picture. There, the only one code block is selected, while two others remains un-selected.

Comment: i don't have enough time right now, but suggest to check `selection` methods , `Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range`, GoTo ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-object-word

Answer (score 1):

After 2 years.

```
Sub SelectOneRangeSameStyle()
Dim curParagraphIndex As Long
Dim curParagraphStyle As Style

'following complex conditions to adjust the curParagraphIndex
'in the case Selection.Star at the beginning of same-style-range
'or the beginning of the document
If Selection.Start <> Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start Or Selection.Start = 0 Then
    curParagraphIndex = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Start).Paragraphs.Count
Else
    curParagraphIndex = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Start).Paragraphs.Count + 1
End If
Set curParagraphStyle = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Style

For i = curParagraphIndex + 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style <> curParagraphStyle Then Exit For
Next i
Selection.End = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i - 1).Range.End

For i = curParagraphIndex - 1 To 1 Step -1
    If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style <> curParagraphStyle Then Exit For
Next i
Selection.Start = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i + 1).Range.Start

End Sub
```